# model for QTreeView crashes when layoutChanged is emitted

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6

I'm trying to write a model (`QAbstractItemModel` child class) to populate data into a QTreeView. I need the items to be checkable and want to later filter out everything that is not checked. To achieve correct hiding of items that have been unchecked when filtering is active, I need to emit `layoutChanged` in my `setData` method. Nevertheless, this one signal (in combination with `layoutAboutToBeChanged`) leads to unpredictable crashes when checking items. I narrowed it down to the following code example, I know two things that will prevent crashes when checking items:

1. Remove the `QSortFilterProxyModel`
2. Do not emit the `layoutChanged` signal

Nevertheless, both are vital to my filtering (which I took out of the example code since it's too much anyway). To reproduce, you can just select an item and press the space bar - won't take long until the app crashes. Does anybody see anything that is wrong with my model? I already checked it with `QtModelTester` from pytest-qt - it's ok.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import string
import sys
from enum import IntEnum
from random import choices
from typing import List, Optional, Tuple, Union, cast

from PyQt6.QtCore import (
    QAbstractItemModel,
    QModelIndex,
    QObject,
    QPersistentModelIndex,
    QSortFilterProxyModel,
    Qt,
    pyqtSignal,
)
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTreeView


class Node:
    """Node inside the tree model."""

    def __init__(self, name: Optional[str]) -> None:
        """Create a new Node."""
        self._name = name
        self._children: List[Node] = []
        self._parent: Optional[Node] = None
        self._check_state: Qt.CheckState = Qt.CheckState.Unchecked

    @property
    def name(self) -> Optional[str]:
        """Return the name of the Node."""
        return self._name

    @property
    def child_count(self) -> int:
        """Return the number of children for the Node."""
        return len(self._children)

    def child(self, row: int) -> Node:
        """Return the child for the given row."""
        return self._children[row]

    @property
    def children(self) -> List[Node]:
        """Return the list of children."""
        return self._children

    @property
    def parent(self) -> Optional[Node]:
        """Return the Node's parent element."""
        return self._parent

    @parent.setter
    def parent(self, parent: Node) -> None:
        """Set the Node's parent element."""
        self._parent = parent

    @property
    def row(self) -> int:
        """Return the row number of the Node."""
        if not self.parent:
            return -1
        return self.parent.children.index(self)

    def add_child(self, child: Node) -> None:
        """Add the given child to the Node's children."""
        child.parent = self
        self._children.append(child)

    def remove_child(self, child: Node) -> None:
        """Remove the given child to the Node's children."""
        self._children.remove(child)
        child.parent = None

    @property
    def check_state(self) -> Qt.CheckState:
        """Return the check state of the Node."""
        return self._check_state

    @check_state.setter
    def check_state(self, check_state: Qt.CheckState) -> None:
        """Set the check state of the Node."""
        self._check_state = check_state


class Model(QAbstractItemModel):
    """Model for data in a QTreeView."""

    add_filter = pyqtSignal(tuple, name="add_filter")
    remove_filter = pyqtSignal(tuple, name="remove_filter")

    class Header(IntEnum):
        """Header definitions."""

        NAME = 0

    def __init__(self, parent: Optional[QObject] = None) -> None:
        """Create a new Model to show data in a QTreeView."""
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._header_labels = {
            Model.Header.NAME: self.tr("Name"),
        }
        self._root = Node(None)
        self._path_cache: List[Tuple[str, ...]] = []
        self._blocked = False

    def flags(self, index: QModelIndex) -> Qt.ItemFlag:
        """Return the flags for the given index and model."""
        if index.isValid():
            return super().flags(index) | Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsUserCheckable
        return super().flags(index)

    def columnCount(  # pylint: disable=invalid-name, no-self-use
        self, _: QModelIndex = QModelIndex()
    ) -> int:
        """Return the column count."""
        return len(self._header_labels)

    def rowCount(  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
        self, parent: QModelIndex = QModelIndex()
    ) -> int:
        """Return the row count."""
        if parent.isValid():
            return cast(Node, parent.internalPointer()).child_count
        count = self._root.child_count
        return count

    def headerData(  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
        self,
        section: int,
        orientation: Qt.Orientation,
        role: int = Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole,
    ) -> Optional[str]:
        """Return the header data for the given section."""
        if (
            orientation == Qt.Orientation.Horizontal
            and role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole
        ):
            return self._header_labels[Model.Header(section)]
        return None

    def on_add_path(self, path: Tuple[str, ...]) -> None:
        """Add a path to the model if it doesn't exist yet."""
        if path not in self._path_cache:
            self._add_path_to_node(path, QModelIndex())
            self._path_cache.append(path)

    def _add_path_to_node(
        self, path: Tuple[str, ...], index: QModelIndex
    ) -> None:
        """Add the path to the given node if it doesn't exist yet."""
        if index.isValid():
            node: Node = index.internalPointer()
        else:
            node = self._root
        for child in node.children:
            if child.name == path[0]:
                self._add_path_to_node(
                    path[1:], self.index(child.row, 0, index)
                )
                return
        new_node = Node(path[0])
        self.beginInsertRows(index, node.child_count, node.child_count)
        node.add_child(new_node)
        self.endInsertRows()
        if path[1:]:
            self._add_path_to_node(
                path[1:], self.index(new_node.row, 0, index)
            )

    def parent(self, child: QModelIndex) -> QModelIndex:  # type: ignore
        """Return the parent index for a given index."""
        if not child.isValid():
            return QModelIndex()

        child_item = child.internalPointer()
        parent_item = child_item.parent

        if parent_item is self._root:
            return QModelIndex()

        return self.createIndex(parent_item.row, 0, parent_item)

    def hasChildren(  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
        self, index: QModelIndex = QModelIndex()
    ) -> bool:
        """Evaluate if children exist for the given index."""
        if index.isValid():
            return bool(index.internalPointer().child_count)
        return bool(self._root.child_count)

    def index(
        self, row: int, col: int, parent: QModelIndex = QModelIndex()
    ) -> QModelIndex:
        """Return an index for the given row and column and parent."""
        # a not existent index should never be requested
        assert self.hasIndex(row, col, parent)

        if not parent.isValid():
            parent_item = self._root
        else:
            parent_item = parent.internalPointer()

        return self.createIndex(row, col, parent_item.child(row))

    def data(  # pylint: disable=no-self-use
        self, index: QModelIndex, role: int = Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole
    ) -> Union[str, Qt.CheckState, None]:
        """Return data for the given index and role."""
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            item = cast(Node, index.internalPointer())
            return item.name
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.CheckStateRole:
            item = cast(Node, index.internalPointer())
            return item.check_state
        return None

    def setData(  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
        self,
        index: QModelIndex,
        value: Qt.CheckState,
        role: int = Qt.ItemDataRole.EditRole,
    ) -> bool:
        """Set the data for the given index and role."""
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.CheckStateRole:
            persistent_idx = QPersistentModelIndex(index)
            self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit([persistent_idx])
            item = cast(Node, index.internalPointer())
            item.check_state = Qt.CheckState(value)
            self.changePersistentIndex(index, index)
            self.dataChanged.emit(
                index, index, [Qt.ItemDataRole.CheckStateRole]
            )
            self.layoutChanged.emit([persistent_idx])
            return True
        return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    APP = QApplication(sys.argv)
    model = Model()
    rand_words = [
        "".join(choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=6))
        for _ in range(20)
    ]
    for char in "ABCDEFG":
        for number in range(100000, 100010):
            for word in rand_words:
                model.on_add_path((char, str(number), word))
    filter_model = QSortFilterProxyModel()
    filter_model.setSourceModel(model)
    view = QTreeView()
    view.setModel(filter_model)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(APP.exec())
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you unnecessarily invoke the changePersistentIndex function as this will make the persistent_idx null (or at least the associated C++ object) causing a segmentation fault since for example the object emitted by layoutChanged has a deleted memory. Solution: remove `self.changePersistentIndex(index, index)`.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. The source code implementation of QAbstractItemModel::changePersistentIndex does something else from what you explain. It removes the index from the list of persistent indexes (as far as I understand), but it does not delete the underlying C++ object. If this was the case, PyQt would raise a TypeError, which it doesn't (it crashes with a memory violation which results from the Qt implementation directly).

It tried you suggested solution, the result is the same, the app still crashes.

Comment: @TilmanK 1) The TypeError should only be thrown when a function receives an object of a different type than expected, in this case it is not. 2) Removing the QPersintentModelIndex object also implies removing the pointers (such as the internal data) so if you later access that object then it will generate a segmentation fault. 3) Removing that line I do not see that error. 4) I recommend using gdb to debug your code.

Comment: You're right, it's a RuntimeError: "RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QWidget has been deleted". Still, if I remove the code, it crashes. What Python version, PyQt version and operating system are you using, if I may ask?

Comment: @TilmanK I use python 3.9.6 with PyQt6 6.1.1 on Linux

Comment: Ok, difference here is, I'm on windows. The problem occurs also with PyQt5 and PySide2/6. When running in VSC I'm getting an error message: QSortFilterProxyModel: index from wrong model passed to mapFromSource